# Error loading modref

Tags: packages, package-options

I have a problem with `modref`, v. 0.9 of 2009/02/02 (generated from the zip archive on CTAN where it is said version 1.0).

I try to use the package `modref` with the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{modref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
Something.
\end{document}
```

LaTeX produces the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section.
```

Maybe the problem is from the use of `\DeclareOption*` with `kvoptions`. Should be `\DeclareDefautOption` instead of `\DeclareOption*` ?

Comment: The package is faulty, it is missing an \ProcessOptions. Why do you want to use it instead of e.g. cleveref?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: In fact, I test the packages found on CTAN dealing with tags in equations to see if they are compatible with my extension `witharrows`.

Comment: Then I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Switch the loading order. But it's quite hopeless to get the package working correctly as it declares options but doesn't process them.

Comment: I sent a mail to the maintainer Niel de Beaudrap (with address found at the end of the documentation available on CTAN) but I had no answer.